# Complicated function Google Sheets: Vacation tracker

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working in [this sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZuBO56trreSpwriLjolxp-EHWSFwaLAoa33EXyatsBw/edit#gid=1202964463)

My first issue: On the sheet **New Summary of Leave** I would like it to only add Leave Type **Vacation** and leave out all types Sick. How can I include this condition? Is there any simpler formula I should use?

Comment: You sheet shows all are set and formula giving output. What is problem you are facing with your formula?

Comment: Hey, as I described: now it sums all the leave types (both vacation and sick). I want to add a condition to the formula where it only sums up vacation.

Comment: Try my below formula and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula. Add another condition and give criteria `Vacation`.

```
=IF(A5<>"",sumifs('Leave responses'!H:H,'Leave responses'!D:D,">="&$E$2,'Leave responses'!D:D,"<="&$G$2,'Leave responses'!D:D,"<=" &now(), 'Leave responses'!C:C,A5,'Leave responses'!F:F,"Vacation"),"")
```